# Problem with building OpenCV for Python 2.6

Tags: python, opencv

I've just downloaded OpenCV's trunk and now I'm trying to build it with MinGW. I read the manual and get .dll's compiled, but that's all - "interfaces/python" contains only some .i and .cmake files. How can I really get new python interface? Where I can find new cv.pyd/libcv.dll.a (because a compiled version from official site crashes sometimes and I saw this bug as "fixed" in Trac)?

Answer (score 0):

Since you downloaded the source from trunk, you will also have to build all of OpenCV before you can use it or the Python wrappers. Have you compiled it?

If not, check the directions on http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide under the "Building OpenCV from source using CMake" heading. There is also a section at the bottom specifc to MinGW.